# asp.net core razor page checkboxes model binding (always false)

Tags: c#, razor-pages

i have a razor page in asp.net core with the following input tag:

```
<input asp-for="chkPref" />
```

in the code-behind i have:

```
public bool chkPref { get; set; }
```

so when i run the app, i can confirm in `Request.Form` that I'm getting...

checkbox checked = `{true,false}`

checkbox unchecked = `{false}`

which is expected, according to https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms/checkboxes (which seems to be the site everyone points to for answers to this issue)

however, that page states that the model binding will figure out that `{true,false}` is actually `true` but i'm getting `false` no matter what.

the website above alludes to the fact that this "just happens"...

> If the checkbox is checked, the posted value will be true,false. The
>   model binder will correctly extract true from the value. Otherwise it
>   will be false.

but that doesn't seem to be working, or at least isn't that obvious how it works.

i'm not exactly sure how you can assign two values (ie - `true`, `false`) to a single `bool` in the first place.

i even tried turning it into a `List<bool>` but that didn't work either. that throws a whole different set of errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe looking at the `Request.Form` gives you the raw form data. What you probably want is to leverage form binder:

you can either mark propertes with [`BindPropertyAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.bindpropertyattribute?view=aspnetcore-3.1) or indicate you expect these specific properties as parameters to your `OnPost` handler (see example below).

Given a razor page

```cs
<form method="post">
    <input asp-for="chkPref" />
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.chkPref2)
    <button>Click</button>
</form>
```

your code-behind could look like so:

```cs
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public bool chkPref { get; set; } // will not get bound

    [BindProperty] // Binder needs to know which properties to work with
    public bool chkPref2 { get; set; }

    public void OnPost(bool chkPref)// PageActionInvoker will pass correct value as parameter
    {
        this.chkPref = chkPref;
    }
}
```

Comment: the key in your answer was to add the `[BindProperty]` which was missing. thx!